# swift collectionCell reuse strategy makes image display incorrect

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit, autolayout

My target: stop animated image in every cell. However, only the first three cell stop successfully at beginning. If I scroll to the fourth or fifth cell, the image is not stoping. Just like the demo below:

[image]

I was wondering if it is because the reusable strategy which cause this problem.
Here is my ViewController Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 16
    private let productItemSpacing: CGFloat = 18
    private var viewModel = testViewModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        viewModel.delegate = self
        setupUI()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Test For CollectionView"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = productItemSpacing
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: 0, right: horizontalPadding)
        return layout
    }()
    
    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let tempLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        tempLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        tempLayout.minimumLineSpacing = productItemSpacing
        tempLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 152, height: 224)
        tempLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: 0, right: horizontalPadding)
        
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: tempLayout)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.register(TestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TestCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.dataSource = self
        view.delegate = self
        view.decelerationRate = .fast
        return view
    }()
    
    func setupUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(120)
            make.left.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(224)
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(5)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TestCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        if let testCell = cell as? TestCollectionViewCell {
            print("<<< enter bindModel")
            let itemData = viewModel.ImageURLs[indexPath.item]
            testCell.bindModel(with: itemData, withIndex: indexPath.item)
            return testCell
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

And Here is my Cell and ViewModel Code:

```
class TestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "CollectionViewCellIdentifier"
    
    private var index = 0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private lazy var backgroundImageView: SDAnimatedImageView = {
        let imageView = SDAnimatedImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var frontImageView: SDAnimatedImageView = {
        let imageView = SDAnimatedImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var indexLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = .orange
        return label
    }()

    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(frontImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(indexLabel)
        
        indexLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(12)
        }
        
        backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.bottom.equalTo(indexLabel.snp.top)
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalTo(152)
            make.height.equalTo(160)
        }
        
        frontImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(112)
            make.height.equalTo(192)
            make.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalTo(indexLabel.snp.top)
        }
        
        indexLabel.text = "\(self.index)"
    }

    public func bindModel(with ImageUrl: String, withIndex: Int) {
        let url = URL(string: ImageUrl)
        self.index = withIndex
        backgroundImageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
        backgroundImageView.stopAnimating()
        
        setupUI()
    }
}

class testViewModel {
    
    public weak var delegate: ViewController?
    public var ImageURLs: [String] = [
        "https://i.postimg.cc/2Sf1tk7K/longmao.gif",
        "https://i.postimg.cc/2Sf1tk7K/longmao.gif",
        "https://i.postimg.cc/2Sf1tk7K/longmao.gif",
        "https://i.postimg.cc/2Sf1tk7K/longmao.gif",
        "https://i.postimg.cc/2Sf1tk7K/longmao.gif"
    ]
    
    public var playedIndex: [Int] = []
    
    init(delegate: ViewController? = nil) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

I try to add `reloadData()` after viewDidAppear, but it is still not working.

Comment: I’m not familiar with `SDWebImage` but I suspect the problem is related to async code when loading the image from a url. You start the load and then stop the animation. But surely the image hasn’t loaded yet (unless it is cached)? Instead of trying to stop the animation, try setting `autoPlayAnimatedImage` to `false` in your animated image views.

Comment: When the cell is reuse its setupUI is call again which add again sunbirds to the cell. You should look at prepareForReuse to put back the cell in the state you would like.

Comment: I put `stopAnimating` into completion of `sd_setImage`, it still playing when I scroll to fourth and fifth cell at first time. So it may not caused by the async code. But `autoPlayAnimatedImage` is worked, thx.

Comment: I tried `prepareFroReuse` but it not working. The animeted image didn't stop for the first 3 cells, and the fourth and fifth image did not show.